# JavaFX 8 Scene BackgroundImage

Tags: css, javafx, background-image

I actual get problem to set an background image to a scene.
I tried it in different ways:

```
public void btn_create_event() throws IOException, Exception{
        Stage curstage = (Stage) config_btn.getScene().getWindow();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FieldLayerController flc = new FieldLayerController();
//        flc.buildField("seeschlacht_background.jpg");
        flc.buildField();
        flc.buildScene();
        flc.buildCamera();
//        String image = FieldLayerController.class.getResource("seeschlacht_background.jpg").toExternalForm(); 
//        flc.root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); "
//                + "-fx-background-position: center center; "
//                + "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;"
//                + "-fx-background-color:transparent;"
//        );
//        flc.root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('seeschlacht_background.jpg')");
        Scene scene = new Scene(flc.root, 1024, 768, true);
//        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("Seeschlacht.css").toExternalForm());
        flc.handleKeyboard(scene, (Node)flc.world);
        flc.handleMouse(scene, (Node)flc.world);
        scene.setCamera(flc.camera);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        curstage.close();
    }
```

These are the Methode from the FieldLayerController which are ncessary to build the window:

```
public void buildScene() {
    System.out.println("buildScene");
    root.getChildren().add(world);
}

public void buildField(){

    final PhongMaterial redMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
    redMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKRED);
    redMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.RED);

    final PhongMaterial whiteMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
    whiteMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.WHITE);
    whiteMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.LIGHTBLUE);

    final PhongMaterial greyMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
    greyMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.GREEN);
    greyMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.DARKGREEN);

    final PhongMaterial lightgreyMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
    greyMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.LIGHTGREY);
    greyMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.GREY);

    //Image img = new Image(img_path);
    //BackgroundImage back_img = new BackgroundImage(img, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

    GraficForm fieldGrafikForm = new GraficForm();
    GraficForm areaGrafikForm = new GraficForm();

    ArrayList<Box> ab = new ArrayList<Box>();

    for (int x = -2; x < 2; x++) {
        for (int z = -2; z < 2; z++) {
            Box box = new Box(50, 0, 50);
            box.setId("X" + (x + 2));
            box.setTranslateX(x + 25 + (x * 50));
            box.setTranslateZ(z + 25 + (z * 50));
            if ((x % 2 == 0 & z % 2 != 0) | (x % 2 != 0 & z % 2 == 0)) {
                box.setMaterial(redMaterial);
            } else {
                box.setMaterial(lightgreyMaterial);
            }
            ab.add(box);
        }
    }

    fieldGrafikForm.getChildren().add(areaGrafikForm);
    areaGrafikForm.getChildren().addAll(ab);
    BattleFieldGroup.getChildren().add(fieldGrafikForm);

    world.getChildren().addAll(BattleFieldGroup);
}
```

So what can i do to set a external img file (the file is in the same Path of the other files and the css-file too) to the Window i create with the FieldLayerController?

Using JavaFX 8 and NetBeans 8. 
I read already the threads to this topic here in stackoverflow:

- => [JavaFX display scene background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710847/javafx-display-scene-background-image)
- => [JavaFX How to set scene background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738146/javafx-how-to-set-scene-background-image)
- => [JavaFx set external background image programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176098/javafx-set-external-background-image-programmatically)

And so on...